# Next.js Facebook share doesn't have an image for the thumbnail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook, next.js

I've tried every solution from the similar questions asked here but nothing has worked for me. I have a page made in Next.js. I wanted to share articles from the page using next-share and I wanted them to have the articles' main image for the share thumbnail but I can't get it to work. There's no image whatsoever in the share on Facebook.

```
if(article){
        return (
            <>
            <Head>
                <title>{article.title}</title>
                <meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com"  crossOrigin="true"/>
                <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"/>
                <meta property="image" content={article.cover_image.url} />
                <meta property="og:title" content={article.title} />
                <meta property="og:image:secure" content={article.cover_image.url} />
                <meta property="og:image:url" content={article.cover_image.url} />
                <meta property="og:site_name" content="Lorem ipsum" />
                <meta property="og:url" content={`${window.location.host}`} />
                <meta property="og:description" content="Lorem ipsum" />
                <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
            </Head>
```

When I go to inspect the article on the page I can see the Head element working well

```
                                            <FacebookShareButton
                                                url={`${window.location.host}${router.asPath}`}
                                                quote={article.subtitle}
                                                hashtag={'#loremipsum'}>
                                                <FacebookIcon size={25} round />
                                            </FacebookShareButton>
                                            <TwitterShareButton
                                                url={`${window.location.host}${router.asPath}`}
                                                title={article.title}>
                                                <TwitterIcon size={25} round />
                                            </TwitterShareButton>
                                            <LinkedinShareButton  url={`${window.location.host}${router.asPath}`}>
                                                <LinkedinIcon size={25} round />
                                            </LinkedinShareButton>
                                            <EmailShareButton
                                                url={`${window.location.host}${router.asPath}`}
                                                subject={article.title}
                                                body="body">
                                                <EmailIcon size={25} round />
                                            </EmailShareButton>
```

Everything besides the image works well. The correct title is there, it's a correct link and quote but the image doesn't seem to show at all. I tried "og:image" and "og:image:secure" which I found in some other thread. Just to clarify, the image doesn't show anywhere but Facebook is the most important to me.

Comment: What URL are you sharing that doesn't work? `<meta property="og:url" content={'${window.location.host}'} />` makes no sense. Facebook doesn't evaluate Javascript. So there is no window.location.host.

Comment: @WizKid What do You mean? ${window.location.host} on render gets substituted with the proper domain? The link works, everything works just the image won't show up. If I share it like this then it's a proper share link, I can visit the website no problem, just the image won't show up

Comment: What is the link you are sharing?

Comment: The Facebook scraper does not care for any client-side JavaScript.